# Debug CalDAVs sync failures with network sniffer, how to be display prettyprinted traffic in terminal

Tags: ssl, debugging, synchronization, webdav, calendar

I need to debug some unsuccessful CalDAV synchronization requests. I have functioning clients, so I can compare working vs broken. The traffic is SSL-encrypted, but I have the key. I have root on a box, that sees this traffic.

I have previously used tools like `tcpdump`, `ngrep`, `*shark`, and others to debug similar problems. This time, the SSL comes into play, and the *sharks can decrypt SSL, but I haven't yet managed to build a suitable tshark command-line, and started wondering, if there aren't more specialized/adapted tools for "Debugging pretty-printed CalDAV XML over HTTPS" in a terminal.

For the record, the working devices are [Androids(with recent DavDroid)](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=at.bitfire.davdroid), and [Outlook 201* (with Free/Open Plugin)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/outlookcaldavsynchronizer/). The non-working are all iDevices on 9.3.2 current as of 07/2016.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this without having SSL keys using [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/):

1. Launch mitmproxy
2. Go to Android's WiFi settings and configure the HTTP proxy to be your PC's IP plus the port `8080` (by default)
3. Open the Android stock browser and go to `mitm.it`. Tap the Android logo and install the certificate for "VPN & apps".